# How can I clamp the rotation to 180 degrees each side or to set on my own clamp degrees when rotating the player head?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objToRotateLookAT;
    public Transform body;
    public float lookAtSpeed;
    public float originalLookSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float distanceToInteract;
    public Animator anim;
    public GameObject text;

    private bool raycastSucceed;
    private Vector3 originalRotation;
    private bool originalRotFlag = true;
    private bool isInstant = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;

        originalRotation = objToRotateLookAT.position;

        if (anim == null)
        {
            anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            if (!raycastSucceed)
                Debug.Log("Did Hit");
            raycastSucceed = true;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.red);

            text.SetActive(true);

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, hit.transform.position) <= distanceToInteract)
            {
                anim.SetBool("Pickup Item", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (raycastSucceed)
                Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
            raycastSucceed = false;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.yellow);

            text.SetActive(false);

            if (originalRotFlag == false)
            {
               
            }
            else
            {
               
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(ray.direction);


        if (isInstant)
        {
            objToRotateLookAT.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
        else
        {
            Quaternion currentRotation = objToRotateLookAT.rotation;

            float angularDifference = Quaternion.Angle(currentRotation, targetRotation);
            // will always be positive (or zero)

            

            if (angularDifference > 0) objToRotateLookAT.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
                                         currentRotation,
                                         targetRotation,
                                         (rotationSpeed * 180 * Time.deltaTime) / angularDifference
                                    );
            else objToRotateLookAT.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Update I'm using the mouse cursor position to rotate the layer head.
The problem is that I can rotate the head to the back so in some cases the body stay facing forward while the head is facing backward.

I want to make some clamp so the head will be able to rotate to the sides and up more or less like a real human head rotation limits.

I just not sure how and where to make the clamp in the Update.

Screenshot when running the game the head and body are fine facing same direction :

[Same direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6lYU.jpg)

but then if I'm moving the mouse too much and rotating the head then :

[The head is facing backward and the body forward.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nyi3.jpg)

I tried this but it's not working nothing changed tried to test a clamp on both targetRotation and currentRotation to limit it to -9 and 9 but nothing changed :

```
private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(ray.direction);

        if (isInstant)
        {
            objToRotateLookAT.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
        else
        {
            Quaternion currentRotation = objToRotateLookAT.rotation;

            targetRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(targetRotation.y, -9f, 9f);
            targetRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetRotation.x, -9f, 9f);
            targetRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp(targetRotation.z, -9f, 9f);

            currentRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.y, -9f, 9f);
            currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, -9f, 9f);
            currentRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.z, -9f, 9f);

            float angularDifference = Quaternion.Angle(currentRotation, targetRotation);
            // will always be positive (or zero)

            if (angularDifference > 0) objToRotateLookAT.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
                                         currentRotation,
                                         targetRotation,
                                         (rotationSpeed * 180 * Time.deltaTime) / angularDifference
                                    );
            else objToRotateLookAT.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
    }
```

Here is a link for a short video clip I recorded showing the problem when the cube is behind the player and that the player head rotation speed is not the same speed as the cube so in most of the time the player is not looking at the cube but looking at it in general direction :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gApXlKv7hKY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-clamp-a-quaternion.370041/#post-5494723 You'd clamp the target rotation.

Comment: After all I did it using IK and it's working great.

Comment: Here is a link for a short video clip I recorded showing the problem when the cube is behind the player and that the player head rotation speed is not the same speed as the cube so in most of the time the player is not looking at the cube but looking at it in general direction :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gApXlKv7hKY&feature=youtu.be